# Unidirectional OneToMany JPA only shows me the first related object "n" times

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have the following table that has many articles. I want to list all 'ventasc' records and inside all kardArt records that have the same 'iddocumento' as pk.

[image]

upgrade:
I changed Set to List but now it shows me all the children with the same value (the first one)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ventasc")
public class Ventasc {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private @Getter @Setter Integer iddocumento;
    private @Getter @Setter String doc1;  
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private @Getter @Setter Date fecha1;
    private @Getter @Setter Double t_neto;
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "iddocumento")
    private @Getter @Setter List<KardArt> kardArts;
    
}
```

This table is linked through 'iddocumento' to sales. I think here is the problem,  it works as pk and fk. I can't edit the database.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "kard_art")
public class KardArt {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private @Getter @Setter Integer iddocumento;

    private @Getter @Setter Double movimiento;
    private @Getter @Setter Double subtotal;
}
```

The commented values ​​are the ones that should bring.

```
{
    "iddocumento": -2147483386,
    "doc1": "PED",
    "fecha1": "2021-10-05 05:00:00",
    "tneto": 5269.96,
    "kardArts": [
      {
        "iddocumento": -2147483386,
        "movimiento": 100,
        "subtotal": 1530
      },
      {
        "iddocumento": -2147483386,
        "movimiento": 100, //100.3
        "subtotal": 1530 //1534.59
      },
      {
        "iddocumento": -2147483386,
        "movimiento": 100, //85.6
        "subtotal": 1530 //1309.68
      },
      {
        "iddocumento": -2147483386,
        "movimiento": 100, //3
        "subtotal": 1530 //45.90
      },
      {
        "iddocumento": -2147483386,
        "movimiento": 100, //3
        "subtotal": 1530 //45.90
      }
    ]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

`mappedBy` is for bi-directional dependencies.

You have to use `@JoinColumn`

```
@JoinColumn(name = "iddocumento")
@OneToMany
private @Getter @Setter Set<KardArt> kardArts;
```

Comment: The same output, it should bring me 46 'KardArts' but it only brings 1

Comment: And you are sure that the data in the database is correct? And did you implement equals and hashcode?

Comment: Yes, the first record is repeated the number of children times. The sum of all subtotal must be equals to tneto. Can I implement hashcode and equals with lombok?

Comment: What do you mean by "the first record is repeated the number of children time"?

Comment: {"iddocumento": -2147483386, "movimiento": 100, "subtotal": 1530} Let's say ventasc has 10 KardArt children. The first record will be repeated 10 times

Comment: why? I assume that this is the problem. you have a OneToMany

Comment: I thought that with One to Many I should bring all your children (not repeat only the first one). I update the json with the true records that it should bring.